# Access attribute on node which has namespace

Tags: groovy, xmlslurper

I have the xml I pasted in the post and I want to use groovy XmlSlurper to access node language with attribute xlink:href that is not null/empty. I read the xml with XmlSlurper in the following way:

```
 def node = xmlSlurper.parseText(xml).declareNamespace(
                xlink:"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        );
```

then I try to access all nodes with name and attribute and process this attribute:

```
node.depthFirst().findAll {
            it.name() == "language" && it["@xlink.href"]?.text().trim()
        }.each {
            println(it["@xlink.href"]?.text())
        }
```

@xlink.href seems to be always empty but it is there. Debugging the code I have noticed that it attribute on node language has value:

```
"{http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink}href" -> "http://prestashop.cartisy.com/api/languages/1"
```

What is the correct way to access xlink.href attribute on node language?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
    <product>
        <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
        <id_manufacturer xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/manufacturers/1"><![CDATA[1]]></id_manufacturer>
        <id_supplier xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/suppliers/1"><![CDATA[1]]></id_supplier>
        <id_category_default xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/categories/5"><![CDATA[5]]></id_category_default>
        <new />
        <cache_default_attribute><![CDATA[1]]></cache_default_attribute>
        <id_default_image xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/images/products/1/1" not_filterable="true"><![CDATA[1]]></id_default_image>
        <id_default_combination xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/combinations/1" not_filterable="true"><![CDATA[1]]></id_default_combination>
        <id_tax_rules_group xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/tax_rule_groups/1"><![CDATA[1]]></id_tax_rules_group>
        <position_in_category not_filterable="true"><![CDATA[0]]></position_in_category>
        <manufacturer_name not_filterable="true"><![CDATA[Fashion Manufacturer]]></manufacturer_name>
        <quantity not_filterable="true"><![CDATA[0]]></quantity>
        <type not_filterable="true"><![CDATA[simple]]></type>
        <id_shop_default><![CDATA[1]]></id_shop_default>
        <reference><![CDATA[demo_1]]></reference>
        <supplier_reference />
        <location />
        <width><![CDATA[0.000000]]></width>
        <height><![CDATA[0.000000]]></height>
        <depth><![CDATA[0.000000]]></depth>
        <weight><![CDATA[0.000000]]></weight>
        <quantity_discount><![CDATA[0]]></quantity_discount>
        <ean13><![CDATA[0]]></ean13>
        <upc />
        <cache_is_pack><![CDATA[0]]></cache_is_pack>
        <cache_has_attachments><![CDATA[0]]></cache_has_attachments>
        <is_virtual><![CDATA[0]]></is_virtual>
        <on_sale><![CDATA[0]]></on_sale>
        <online_only><![CDATA[0]]></online_only>
        <ecotax><![CDATA[0.000000]]></ecotax>
        <minimal_quantity><![CDATA[1]]></minimal_quantity>
        <price><![CDATA[19.980000]]></price>
        <wholesale_price><![CDATA[4.950000]]></wholesale_price>
        <unity />
        <unit_price_ratio><![CDATA[0.000000]]></unit_price_ratio>
        <additional_shipping_cost><![CDATA[0.00]]></additional_shipping_cost>
        <customizable><![CDATA[0]]></customizable>
        <text_fields><![CDATA[0]]></text_fields>
        <uploadable_files><![CDATA[0]]></uploadable_files>
        <active><![CDATA[1]]></active>
        <redirect_type><![CDATA[404]]></redirect_type>
        <id_product_redirected><![CDATA[0]]></id_product_redirected>
        <available_for_order><![CDATA[1]]></available_for_order>
        <available_date><![CDATA[0000-00-00]]></available_date>
        <condition><![CDATA[new]]></condition>
        <show_price><![CDATA[1]]></show_price>
        <indexed><![CDATA[1]]></indexed>
        <visibility><![CDATA[both]]></visibility>
        <advanced_stock_management><![CDATA[0]]></advanced_stock_management>
        <date_add><![CDATA[2014-10-29 21:55:10]]></date_add>
        <date_upd><![CDATA[2014-10-29 21:55:10]]></date_upd>
        <meta_description>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/1" />
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/2" />
            <language id="3" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/3" />
        </meta_description>
        <meta_keywords>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/1" />
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/2" />
            <language id="3" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/3" />
        </meta_keywords>
        <meta_title>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/1" />
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/2" />
            <language id="3" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/3" />
        </meta_title>
        <link_rewrite>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[faded-short-sleeve-tshirts]]></language>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/2"><![CDATA[faded-short-sleeve-tshirts]]></language>
            <language id="3" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/3"><![CDATA[faded-short-sleeve-tshirts]]></language>
        </link_rewrite>
        <name>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts]]></language>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/2"><![CDATA[Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts]]></language>
            <language id="3" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/3"><![CDATA[Faded Short Sleeve T-shirts]]></language>
        </name>
        <description>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[<p>Fashion has been creating well-designed collections since 2010. The brand offers feminine designs delivering stylish separates and statement dresses which has since evolved into a full ready-to-wear collection in which every item is a vital part of a woman's wardrobe. The result? Cool, easy, chic looks with youthful elegance and unmistakable signature style. All the beautiful pieces are made in Italy and manufactured with the greatest attention. Now Fashion extends to a range of accessories including shoes, hats, belts and more!</p>]]></language>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/2"><![CDATA[<p>Fashion has been creating well-designed collections since 2010. The brand offers feminine designs delivering stylish separates and statement dresses which has since evolved into a full ready-to-wear collection in which every item is a vital part of a woman's wardrobe. The result? Cool, easy, chic looks with youthful elegance and unmistakable signature style. All the beautiful pieces are made in Italy and manufactured with the greatest attention. Now Fashion extends to a range of accessories including shoes, hats, belts and more!</p>]]></language>
            <language id="3" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/3"><![CDATA[<p>Fashion has been creating well-designed collections since 2010. The brand offers feminine designs delivering stylish separates and statement dresses which has since evolved into a full ready-to-wear collection in which every item is a vital part of a woman's wardrobe. The result? Cool, easy, chic looks with youthful elegance and unmistakable signature style. All the beautiful pieces are made in Italy and manufactured with the greatest attention. Now Fashion extends to a range of accessories including shoes, hats, belts and more!</p>]]></language>
        </description>
        <description_short>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[<p>Faded short sleeve t-shirt with high neckline. Soft and stretchy material for a comfortable fit. Accessorize with a straw hat and you're ready for summer!</p>]]></language>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/2"><![CDATA[<p>Faded short sleeve t-shirt with high neckline. Soft and stretchy material for a comfortable fit. Accessorize with a straw hat and you're ready for summer!</p>]]></language>
            <language id="3" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/3"><![CDATA[<p>Faded short sleeve t-shirt with high neckline. Soft and stretchy material for a comfortable fit. Accessorize with a straw hat and you're ready for summer!</p>]]></language>
        </description_short>
        <available_now>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/1"><![CDATA[In stock]]></language>
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/2"><![CDATA[In stock]]></language>
            <language id="3" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/3"><![CDATA[In stock]]></language>
        </available_now>
        <available_later>
            <language id="1" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/1" />
            <language id="2" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/2" />
            <language id="3" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/3" />
        </available_later>
        <associations>
            <categories node_type="categories">
                <categories xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/categories/2">
                    <id><![CDATA[2]]></id>
                </categories>
                <categories xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/categories/3">
                    <id><![CDATA[3]]></id>
                </categories>
                <categories xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/categories/4">
                    <id><![CDATA[4]]></id>
                </categories>
                <categories xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/categories/5">
                    <id><![CDATA[5]]></id>
                </categories>
            </categories>
            <images node_type="images">
                <images xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/images/products/1/1">
                    <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
                </images>
                <images xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/images/products/1/2">
                    <id><![CDATA[2]]></id>
                </images>
                <images xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/images/products/1/3">
                    <id><![CDATA[3]]></id>
                </images>
                <images xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/images/products/1/4">
                    <id><![CDATA[4]]></id>
                </images>
            </images>
            <combinations node_type="combinations">
                <combinations xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/combinations/1">
                    <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
                </combinations>
                <combinations xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/combinations/2">
                    <id><![CDATA[2]]></id>
                </combinations>
                <combinations xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/combinations/3">
                    <id><![CDATA[3]]></id>
                </combinations>
                <combinations xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/combinations/4">
                    <id><![CDATA[4]]></id>
                </combinations>
                <combinations xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/combinations/5">
                    <id><![CDATA[5]]></id>
                </combinations>
                <combinations xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/combinations/6">
                    <id><![CDATA[6]]></id>
                </combinations>
            </combinations>
            <product_option_values node_type="product_option_values">
                <product_option_values xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/product_option_values/1">
                    <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
                </product_option_values>
                <product_option_values xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/product_option_values/13">
                    <id><![CDATA[13]]></id>
                </product_option_values>
                <product_option_values xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/product_option_values/14">
                    <id><![CDATA[14]]></id>
                </product_option_values>
                <product_option_values xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/product_option_values/2">
                    <id><![CDATA[2]]></id>
                </product_option_values>
                <product_option_values xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/product_option_values/3">
                    <id><![CDATA[3]]></id>
                </product_option_values>
            </product_option_values>
            <product_features node_type="product_features">
                <product_features xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/product_features/5">
                    <id><![CDATA[5]]></id>
                    <custom><![CDATA[0]]></custom>
                    <id_feature_value xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/product_feature_values/5"><![CDATA[5]]></id_feature_value>
                </product_features>
                <product_features xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/product_features/6">
                    <id><![CDATA[6]]></id>
                    <custom><![CDATA[0]]></custom>
                    <id_feature_value xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/product_feature_values/11"><![CDATA[11]]></id_feature_value>
                </product_features>
                <product_features xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/product_features/7">
                    <id><![CDATA[7]]></id>
                    <custom><![CDATA[0]]></custom>
                    <id_feature_value xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/product_feature_values/17"><![CDATA[17]]></id_feature_value>
                </product_features>
            </product_features>
            <tags node_type="tags" />
            <stock_availables node_type="stock_availables">
                <stock_availables xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/stock_availables/1">
                    <id><![CDATA[1]]></id>
                    <id_product_attribute><![CDATA[0]]></id_product_attribute>
                </stock_availables>
                <stock_availables xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/stock_availables/8">
                    <id><![CDATA[8]]></id>
                    <id_product_attribute><![CDATA[1]]></id_product_attribute>
                </stock_availables>
                <stock_availables xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/stock_availables/9">
                    <id><![CDATA[9]]></id>
                    <id_product_attribute><![CDATA[2]]></id_product_attribute>
                </stock_availables>
                <stock_availables xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/stock_availables/10">
                    <id><![CDATA[10]]></id>
                    <id_product_attribute><![CDATA[3]]></id_product_attribute>
                </stock_availables>
                <stock_availables xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/stock_availables/11">
                    <id><![CDATA[11]]></id>
                    <id_product_attribute><![CDATA[4]]></id_product_attribute>
                </stock_availables>
                <stock_availables xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/stock_availables/12">
                    <id><![CDATA[12]]></id>
                    <id_product_attribute><![CDATA[5]]></id_product_attribute>
                </stock_availables>
                <stock_availables xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/stock_availables/13">
                    <id><![CDATA[13]]></id>
                    <id_product_attribute><![CDATA[6]]></id_product_attribute>
                </stock_availables>
            </stock_availables>
            <accessories node_type="products" />
            <product_bundle node_type="products" />
        </associations>
    </product>
</prestashop>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's `@ns:attr` and **not** `@ns.attr`:

```
def node = new groovy.util.XmlSlurper().parseText('''\
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<prestashop xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
<meta_description>
<language id="1" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/1" />
<language id="2" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/2" />
<language id="3" xlink:href="http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/3" />
</meta_description>
</prestashop>
''').declareNamespace(
    xlink:"http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink")

node.depthFirst().findAll {
    it.name() == "language" && it["@xlink:href"]?.text()?.trim()
    //                                  ~~~
}.each {
    println(it["@xlink:href"]?.text())
    //               ~~~
}
//=> http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/1
//=> http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/2
//=> http://prestashop.test.com/api/languages/3
```